# Shared sections in master layout containing db data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

In my Laravel 5.1 app, I have a master layout with a shared section, let's say a sidebar with a list of the 5 most recent site posts. The section content is dynamic (elaborated from a db query), but identical on every website page.

To obtain this, in the master layout I could @include a sub-view containing the sidebar code, but that would still mean repeating the same db query in each controller action, which is a lot of code repetition. I'm sure there is a smarter way to obtain this, but I couldn't figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think you looking for cache.. if you don't cache your queries than yes in every request there gonna be db query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures) under sub views you can pass data into the include such as

```
@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

Then you only need to pass the data into the master layout.

EDIT: [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers) are what you were looking for it seems

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem is not passing data to the layout, but avoiding code repetition in controller action. Where should I put the query code so that it is executed on every action of a particular controller?

Comment: Why would you want it on every action of a controller? You could use middleware and attach it that way, you could create a viewcomposer, I am pretty sure that it would it.

Comment: I looked into view composers, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the tip!